# XmlNodeReader returns {None}

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xml-deserialization

I'm currently having trouble deserializing an XmlDocument from a web service call, here is my code : -

```
 public void getTest(XmlDocument requestDoc)
    {
        XmlDocument results = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataRequest));
        DataRequest req;
        XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(requestDoc.DocumentElement);
        req = (DataRequest)serial.Deserialize(reader);
        response.write(req.toString());
    }
```

now, the trouble I am having is that the XmlNodeReader just contains "{None}" when I step through in debug, the requestDoc definatly has the expected XML structure, any ideas?

Kind regards
Gib

Comment: Did you consider using `Linq to XML` instead `XmlDocument`

Comment: unfortunatly I'm workign to a specification and must accept an XmlDocument as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "none" probably just means it hasn't started iterating yet, and is at BOF (for want of a better term). It should still work. Usually, if it doesn't it means the namespaces are incorrect - double-check for `xmlns` in the source.

This works fine, for example:

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<Test foo=""bar""></Test>");
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
        using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement))
        {
            var test = (Test)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Foo);
        }

    }
    [XmlAttribute("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```